# TypeError: Super expression must be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to make some inheritances in my App, and I'm getting error: `TypeError: Super expression must be null or a function, not undefined`

BaseFile.js:

```
export class BaseClass{

    constructor(name)
    {
        this.type = name;
    }

}

export class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass{  
}
```

And my second file is:

```
import {ExtendedClass} from './BaseFile';

export class MyClass extends ExtendedClass {
    constructor() 
    {
        super('default');
    }
}
```

I can't find any mistake here...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What happens if you add a constructor to `ExtendedClass` that just calls `super();` ?

Comment: Are those your only files? Any circular dependencies? On which line do you get that error?

Comment: @Jankapunkt Not necessary. The term "super expression" refers to the `extends` clause.

Comment: Neither `constructor(name) { super(name); }` and `constructor() { super(); }` doesn't work.

Comment: @Bergi I have other dependencies in MyClass. And this line is highlighted: `export class MyClass extends ExtendedClass`